# How many books can each home in Skyrim hold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

How many books can the automatic bookshelves in each house hold? Are there any in the base game which can hold a copy of every non-spell book in the game? (Books, not 0-weight notes.)

So basically, what is the total bookshelf capacity for each house, including Hearthfire ones with the library wing, and how does that compare to the total number of non-spell books?

Footnote: I'm asking this for a stock Skyrim game with only Bethesda's official add-ons installed, as a console player would.

Comment: I had a very pedantic reason to keep this open ... But upon re-reading that question and its answers ... The question is a dupe, even if all the info I'm looking for isn't quite in those answers ... Yet.